# Debouncing on OnChange Event - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search form which is changing my params on my page.
It's actually working fine, however whenever you input any character at all, it will automatically refresh the page and re-fetch results. This is not what I want.

Is there a better way to action this, e.g debounce the search results for an idle time on the user input OR dynamically fetch?

See my code below:

```
  function handleParamChange(e) {
    const param = e.target.name //name may be desc
    const value = e.target.value
    setParams(prevParams => {
      return { ...prevParams, [param]: value}
    })
  }
```

```
<SearchForm params={params} onParamChange={handleParamChange}/>
```

This will then be fed to component as such.

```
const SearchForm = ({params, onParamChange}) => {

  return (
    <GeneralFilterContainer>
        <TextField id="standard-basic" 
                   label="Search Roles" 
                   variant="standard"  
                   size="small"
                   onChange={onParamChange}
                   value={params.what}
                   name="what"
                   type="text"
                   />
    </GeneralFilterContainer>
  )
}

export default SearchForm
```

As above, i just want to debounce and dynamically fetch rather then it just reload every time.

Regards

Comment: Adding a debounce here is a good idea. You could use [lodash](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-debounce-method/) or something else, there are a ton of examples on the web.

Comment: Thanks foxxy, how would you reccomend I implement it into this above code? i'm quite new! Is this a normal issue that after each character typed it refreshes the app?

Answer (score 0):

The `onChange` event gets fired after each key the user types, so yes, your app in this case will reload after each keypress. A simple solution woulb be to add this function in your component:

```js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;

  return function executedFunction() {
    var context = this;
    var args = arguments;
        
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };

    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

which i got from [here](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-use-the-debounce-function-in-javascript). After that, change your `onChange` event to this:

```js
onChange={debounce(onParamChange, 250)}
```

I hope this works, i can't test it right now.

Comment: you might want to memoize that function and also handle unmount properly

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti you shouldn't define this function inside a component

Comment: no, you probably want to define a hook like `useDebounced()` where the callback is memoized with (for example) `useCallback()` and you call `clearTimeout` when the component is unmounted (`useEffect(() => () => clearTimeout(...), [])`) otherwise it'll cause useless additional re-renderings and it might fire right after a component has been unmounted.